# Draggable scrollable sheet in a list view as in google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, user-interface, flutter-widget

I am a flutter newbie.

May I know how it is possible to make the draggable scrollable sheet to display on dragging up a container in a list view, as in google maps in flutter?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jERI7.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyGC6.jpg)

[draggable scrollable sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Modri.jpg)

Comment: Just to understand your question, You want to implement a container that you can drag and scroll around or you want to implement google maps?

Comment: No I just needed to know how the container on dragging up changes into a draggable scrollable sheet. I mentioned up about the google maps is for example.

Comment: Okay, I think I have understood. You can use `GestureDetector.onPanUpdate` to check whether the user has swipe either way. Then you can write a function that will present the draggable container. Or you can place them in a stack of draggable container and container then interchange them when the screen is swipe.